# Is there a better way to use NSE in a function to concatenate dataframe columns?

Tags: r, rlang, tidyeval, nse

### Background

I'm trying to get my grip on meta-programming methods in [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/quasiquotation.html), and not being a programmer by background, it is taking some effort.  I am trying to write functions to manipulate dataframe columns without quoting (tidyverse style).  This is easy enough when actually using `dplyr` verbs by using `enquo()` and `!!` or curly-curly `{{ }}`, but less intuitive when I want to do something inside a function akin to `var <- c(df$colA, df$colB)` which doesn't require a tidyverse verb.

### Setup

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df <- tibble(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
             col2 = c("D", "E", "F"),
             col3 = c("G", "H", "I"),
             col4 = c("J", "K", "L"))
> df
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  col1  col2  col3  col4 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A     D     G     J    
2 B     E     H     K    
3 C     F     I     L
```

### The Function

Most of the time, the dataframe(s) I'll be using have the same column names, so setting them as defaults will save coding.  This works, but seems excessively verbose for all the use of `enquo()`, `expr()`, `!!`, and `eval_tidy()` in this small example:

```
myFun3 <- function(df, var1 = col1, var2 = col2){
  var1 <- enquo(var1)
  var2 <- enquo(var2)

  var3 <- expr(c(!!var1, !!var2))
  #print(var3)
  out <- tibble(var_out = eval_tidy(var3, df))
  return(out)
}

> myFun3(df)
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  var_out
  <chr>  
1 A      
2 B      
3 C      
4 D      
5 E      
6 F   
   
> myFun3(df, col3, col4)  # For when I have column names that aren't my defaults
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  var_out
  <chr>  
1 G      
2 H      
3 I      
4 J      
5 K      
6 L
```

If I throw a `print(var3)` into the function and rerun it, I can see the expression is `c(~col1, ~col2)`, and I initially thought I could shorten the function like this:

```
myFun4 <- function(df, var1 = col1, var2 = col2){
  var3 <- expr(c(ensym(var1), ensym(var2)))   # ditched the enquo() and tried directly inserting parameter values with ensym()
  print(var3)
  out <- tibble(var_out = eval_tidy(var3, df))
  return(out)
}

> myFun4(df)
c(ensym(var1), ensym(var2))
# A tibble: 2 × 1
  var_out
  <list> 
1 <sym>  
2 <sym>
```

As you can see above, my failure above is that symbols never get evaluated as they are preserved by the `expr()`.  I was closer before when I kept `var1` and `var2` as quosures.

### Guidance Sought

Can `myFun3()` be written in a more concise manner than I have done?  I'm focused on reading how this works in `rlang`, but the problem I'm showing above is fundamentally base R (concatenating two columns of a dataframe).  In other circumstances, I am writing functions using `dplyr` verbs, so I am thinking that staying with tidy evaluation is appropriate here, but maybe I should be doing this above with base R NSE (? -- Would that make a difference?).  Thank you for any clarity on my efforts above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options to get the ball rolling.  You could turn the unquoted variable names into quoted variable names and then us `df[[var1]]` or something like that.  That's what I do in `myFun3()` below.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rlang'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     %@%, flatten, flatten_chr, flatten_dbl, flatten_int, flatten_lgl,
#>     flatten_raw, invoke, splice

df <- tibble(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"),
             col2 = c("D", "E", "F"),
             col3 = c("G", "H", "I"),
             col4 = c("J", "K", "L"))
```

```r
myFun3 <- function(df, var1 = col1, var2 = col2){
  var1 <- as_label(enquo(var1))
  var2 <- as_label(enquo(var2))
  out <- tibble(var_out = c(df[[var1]], df[[var2]]))
  return(out)
}

myFun3(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 1
#>   var_out
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 A      
#> 2 B      
#> 3 C      
#> 4 D      
#> 5 E      
#> 6 F
```

You also don't have to leave the `dplyr` world, because for this particular problem, you could use `reframe()` to make the new dataset.  Whether this works as well your intended real-world scenario, I'm not sure.  That's what I do in `myFun3b()` below:

```r
myFun3b <- function(df, var1 = col1, var2 = col2){
  out <- df %>% reframe(var_out = c({{var1}}, {{var2}}))
  return(out)
}

myFun3b(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 1
#>   var_out
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 A      
#> 2 B      
#> 3 C      
#> 4 D      
#> 5 E      
#> 6 F
```

You could also do it by using the inject operator (`!!`) on an `ensym()` using `with(df, ...)` as in `myFun3c()`.

```r
myFun3c <- function(df, var1 = col1, var2 = col2){
  out <- tibble(var_out = with(df, c(!!ensym(var1), !!ensym(var2))))
  return(out)
}
myFun3c(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 1
#>   var_out
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 A      
#> 2 B      
#> 3 C      
#> 4 D      
#> 5 E      
#> 6 F
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I like the suggestion of `reframe()` b/c it didn't occur to me and I've only used it once that I can recall.  May not work in all my cases, but I'm trying to get a strong grasp of rlang anyway, and the `df$col1` usage is fuzzy.  Is there any risk associated with mixing base R (`with()`) and rlang (`!!ensym()`)? My gut has me avoid crossing those streams, but maybe that's unnecessarily conservative?

Comment: I don't think there's a problem crossing these two.  In fact, if you look at help for the injection operation - `help("!!")` - it actually uses base `with()` in some of its examples, noting that since `with()` is a base function, it only accepts calls and naked symbols, which is why you need `ensym()`.